# how can I use add_action run another function when publishing new post?

Tags: actions

I want to call my customClass when ever new post publish or update.but after I add  **add_action** to my code , the function will run multiple times even before posting new post. can anyone help me? what is the right solution? I 've been searching for some days but i didn't find the right answer.

**custom.php**

```
class customClass{
   function dothisfunction($mobiles , $message ){
      //send sms to $mobiles number with $message body      
   }
}
```

**function.php:**
include('custom.php');
$mobiles = '09112443344';
$message = 'new msg testing';

```
$myClass = new customClass();

add_action( 'publish_post', array( $myClass ,'dothisfunction'), 10, 2 );//
do_action( 'publish_post', $mobiles, $message );
```

Comment: It's because you're manually calling `do_action()`. This will trigger that action on every page load. Why are you doing this?

Comment: yes your right it will trigger on every page load. then how should i send my parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're partly there. This is the code you should be using:

```php
add_action( 'publish_post', array( $myClass ,'dothisfunction' ), 10, 2 );
```

*You* can't pass parameters to the action that's being executed. You can only "hook" into the action after `do_action` is called, and whatever parameters have been added to that action.

If there are particular variables that you want that function `dothisfunction` to have that weren't originally sent along with the event, you'll have to get them from somewhere else.

You can't "add" more parameters to a hook - you can only grab the variable that were sent with it.

So you could probably do something like:

```php
    class customClass {

        public $smsMobileNumber;

        public $message;

        function dothisfunction( $postId, $post ) {

            $fullMessage = sprintf( $this->message, $postId, $post->post_title );

            // code to send SMS message
        }
    }

    $myClass = new customClass();
    $myClass->smsMobileNumber = '012345456';
    $myClass->message = 'Post published with ID %s and title %s';

    add_action( 'publish_post', array( $myClass ,'dothisfunction' ), 10, 2 );
```

So you can see here that you're populating your SMS mobile number and message template in your custom class and then you hook into the `publish_post` action. You then create a message which includes your new post ID and you have your code that sends your SMS message.

You'll see in the function `dothisfunction` that I can only use the parameters that were originally sent in this action. In this case, after I review the WordPress source code, I see that this hook is fired with 2 parameters: the post ID, and the Post itself. That's **all** I can use in my hooked-function. I must supply any other parameters myself in another way.

Also worth noting that **your code doesn't** need to call `do_action`. WordPress will run this action and all you need to do is hook into it.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Would you like to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you?